# Is it possible to add a property to an iframe window object before it loads such that the value is available to scripts in the frame?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to add a property to an iframe's window before the page loads its content. I would like it set so that scripts loaded on the source have access to that property.

As an example, this is what I am attempting to do:

```html
<!- index.html ->
<body>
  <script type="module">
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.src = 'about:blank'

    const onLoad1 = new Promise(res => iframe.onload = res)
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)
    await onLoad1

    iframe.contentWindow.foo = 'something'
    console.log(iframe.contentWindow.foo)

    const onLoad2 = new Promise(res => iframe.onload = res)
    iframe.src = 'frame.html' // same origin
    await onLoad2

    console.log(iframe.contentWindow.foo) // currently undefined
  </script>
</body>
```

```
<!- frame.html ->
<script>
  console.log(window.foo) // currently undefined
</script>
```

I realise the `contentWindow` is a new `Window` because re-assigning the `src` property triggers a new page load.

I was hopeful that travelling from `about:blank` to a same origin path would grant me special powers persist properties set on the `window` but that wasn't the case.

Currently (what I am trying to avoid), I am resorting to emitting a custom event and capturing that asynchronously within the frame. This is a cumbersome dance and not ideal for situations where values must be known synchronously.

```
<!- index.html ->
<body>
  <script type="module">
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.src = 'frame.html'

    const onLoad1 = new Promise(res => iframe.onload = res)
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)
    await onLoad1

    function sendValue() {
      iframe.contentWindow.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('custom:onload', { detail: 'foo' }))
    }

    iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('custom:request:onload', sendValue)
    sendValue()
  </script>
</body>
```

```
<!- frame.html ->
<body>
  <script async type="module">
    const onfoo = new Promise(
      res => window.addEventListener('custom:request:onload', e => res(e.detail))
    
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('custom:request:onload'))
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to communicate via the [Message events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) with the iframe ..?

Comment: Yep, I use `dispatchEvent` currently because I need to be able to pass complex JavaScript objects across same-origin frames - but the asynchronous nature means it's a cumbersome dance between the sender/receiver and values that are required synchronously have to be passed through some other mechanism (query string, hash, name)